# Do WebSocket SendAsync() synchronously

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, websocket

I have a Websocket `HTTPListener` as a server, and the clients are [`WebSocket`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.websocket(v=vs.110).aspx)'s

I keep all the current clients in a list, and I want to have a function which sends information to all the clients asynchronously.

So what I currently have is:

```
private async Task SendToAll(byte[] buffer)
{
    foreach (WebSocket webSocket in clients)
    {
        await Send(webSocket, buffer, buffer.Length);
    }
}

private async Task Send(WebSocket webSocket, byte[] buffer, int bufferLength)
{
    try
    {
        await webSocket.SendAsync(
            new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, bufferLength),
            WebSocketMessageType.Text, true,
            CancellationToken.None);
    }
    catch (WebSocketException ex)
    {
        RemoveClient(webSocket, WebSocketCloseStatus.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Problem is, if a have a big number of clients I'm opening a meaningful number of threads, which is a waste to me. So I thought that the `Send()` function could occur synchronously, but `WebSocket`s doesn't have a synchronous functions, which is strange to me.

As I believe it's not a good practice to run Task functions synchronously, is there a good way of doing it? I don't want just to drop the `await`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Problem is, if a have a big number of clients I'm opening a meaningful number of threads, which is a waste to me.

Two questions:

1. Have you measured the threads? How much exactly is "a meaningful number"?
2. Does the performance testing indicate that these threads are a "waste"?

Since writing to a network socket [doesn't consume a thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html), the code is already making appropriate use of the thread pool. I would not expect the number of threads to increase significantly in this code. If there *are* a handful of additional threads being created, then it's because those additional threads *are useful*. It's difficult to do better for such I/O-bound operations.

On an unrelated side note, I would recommend sending to all clients concurrently, rather than one at a time:

```
private async Task SendToAll(byte[] buffer)
{
  var tasks = clients.Select(webSocket => Send(webSocket, buffer, buffer.Length));
  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: After testing, my question is definitely about over-optimizing which is unnecessary. Sometimes it's good to hear it again. Thank you!